# Get all subitems from Object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working in Vue and trying to POST some values which I collected to the server, but the current implementation I found a little bit frustrating.

I have a funcion in a Vue-method which POSTs the values which I 'collected' from the original Object:

```
    var inputvalues = {};
    // Get values from all inputs
    for (key in this.entries) {
        var val = this.entries[key].value;

        if (val != undefined) {
            console.log(key,val);
            Vue.set(inputvalues,key,val)
        }
    }

    [ Here is the AJAX part which sends 'inputvalues' to the server - not so relevant]
```

And the Object looks like below:

```
entries: {
    something1: {
        options: {
            "option1":"Option 1",
            "option2":"Option 2",
            "option3":"Option 3"
        },
        visible:true,
        value:undefined
    },
    something2: {
        options: {
            "one":"One",
            "two":"Two",
        },
        visible:true,
        value:undefined
    }
}
```

This 'works', but I'm not satisfied with the result.

Isn't there anything like `this.entries[].value` which fetchs all values of this Object, or should I write the values of the input fields in a separate Object, or ... I don't know which way is the *right* way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's in the question already. `entries` *is* `this.entries` @JonasW.

Comment: "Option 1" should not have a value on it's own, only `something1.value` should

Comment: If I do `var inputvalues = this.entries;` I would be sending a lot of unnecessary stuff to the server. I only need the key and the 'value' @JonasW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe slightly more elegant:

```
const inputvalues = Object.entries(this.entries)
   .map(([k, v]) => ([k, v.value]))
   .reduce((res, [k, v]) => (v !== undefined && (res[k] = v), res), {});
```

Or a bit less functional:

```
const inputvalues = {};

for(const [key, obj] of Object.entries(this.entries))
  if(obj.value !== undefined)
    inputvalues[key] = obj.value;
```

Comment: I think for maintaining purposes the second is better, thanks for that. I saw the first one and was a bit overwhelmed of that much functionality going on in one line.

Comment: One question though: Why `const` and not `var`?

Comment: Cause you should make everything `const`ant by default. Type changes are a bad thing for 1) readability 2) stability 3) performance (maybe), so you should try to use constants as much as possible. If you wanna reassign it for a good reason though then using `let` or `var` is totally fine.

Comment: Uh oh! I just realized that I had some basic knoweledge wrong. Since ever I thought that `const` means that the variable *value* cannot be changed after it was assigned and `var` can. Now I know that it only fixes *types*. Thank you!

Comment: @fusseldieb no your knowledge was right. But if the value can't change the type can't change too. And while you can't do `inputvalues = 3` you can still mutate all the properties of the object, so there is no real need to reassign.

Comment: Ohh, okay. Thank you again.

Comment: @fusseldieb glad to help :)